# simple_form_for redirect on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, simple-form

I'm noob in Ruby on Rails and I have a dumb question:
in my session_controller I have

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

in routes I have
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'

in new.html.haml I have

```
  = simple_form_for :session do |f|
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :password
    = f.button :submit, 'Sign in!'
```

When I press "Sign in" button, I expect that method "create" will be called (how it works in my user model), but debug shows me "new" method and I have "authenticity_token" withot filling email and password.
Could somebody explane me what heppens?
I don't understand when method "new" calls and then other methods.

Answer (score 5):

This behavior has nothing to do with the `simple_form`. You don't specify an url for your action to be called, you don't pass any model to infer its path, so you'll end up with the `url_for()` method called on empty hash. The result of this calling is the current page, which is obviously is the same path where your form was displayed, but with the `POST` as the HTML-verb.

To call your `sessions_path` instead of your `new_session_path` you can do the following:

```
= simple_form_for :session, url: :sessions do |f|
```

Being processed through the `url_for`, it's effectively the same as specifying `url: sessions_path` but is making a magician out of you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use haml I use erb, but I suspect the work alike.  In erb your form would need to call an action for example:

```
    form_for :session, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f|
```

That would call the create method of your session controller.  So I guess haml would be

```
    simple_form_for :session, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f|
```

hope this helps